# pdflatex seems to ignore -output-directory

Tags: pdftex

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project
   pdf
   src
```

My source file is located in `src`, and I'm trying to run `pdflatex` from the `project` directory using a command like this:

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error src/foo.tex -output-directory pdf
```

The compilation works, but `foo.pdf` ends up in `project`, rather than in `pdf`, which is obviously not what I want. I would assume that `-output-directory` would take care of this, but it doesn't seem to. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the order is important here. The command is: `latex [options] [file] [commands]`. But `-output-directory` is not a command; it is an option.

Comment: @jon Thanks - that actually solved it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the trusty `man` page for `tex` and `pdftex` (the command name):

```sh
tex [options] [&format] [file|\commands]
```

So the order is important: options go before the filename. Therefore, you should use:

```sh
pdflatex -halt-on-error -output-directory pdf src/foo.tex
```

Comment: Arg! I spent so much time on finding this! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ingomueller.net -- Haha, always the worst! Glad you found it eventually!

Comment: Is this something specific to `pdflatex` or is it common for *nix terminal tool options/files to be order sensitive? I feel like I usually interchange these without a problem.

Comment: Note that on your machine, you might need to do `-output-directory=pdf` (i.e the equals sign instead of a space)

Answer (score 4):

I tried jon's solution, but I got an error regarding where the .log file to write to, so I found this:

```
pdflatex -aux-directory=<DIRECTORY OF LOG & AUX FILES> -output-directory=<DIRECTORY OF OUTPUT PDF FILE> FILENAME.tex
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Note that -aux-directory is specific to MikTeX, and so won't work on MacTeX or TeXLive. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126897/211532