# Why does the texlive version of (lua-)latex not have the `--aux-directory`switch?

Tags: luatex, miktex, texlive

On Windows (MiKTeX), lualatex has a `--aux-directory` switch.
On Linux (TeXLive) it does not.
Why is that? If it is a downstream patch only present in MiKTeX, why is it not in upstream lualatex?

It seems like the same issue affects pdflatex and other engines

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96767/mactex-aux-directory-dir

Comment: your up/downs stream references are a bit confusing in this context, miktex and texlive are not derived from each other so you wouldn't normally say miktex is downstream of texlive. but anyway `aux-directory`  is miktex specific, it is mostly covered by the functionality of the `-output-directory`  option in texlive, Personally I think either of them is a really bad idea over and over again we see people with broken documents as aux files have been directed to some non standard place and then the user has failed to configure every other program in the tex pipeline to find them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Referencing to "upstream", I meant lualatex, not texlive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've seen these two switches break TeX a lot too, but I like them very much because they help me finding my source files again. Having tens of generated files mixed between my source code makes it hard to work. Having them in a separate folder makes it nice and clean. Also, having output and aux dir separate is more like programming: aux directory is the ccache equivalent, output directory is the bindir equivalent.

Comment: @genodeftest I've seen that argument before, but I don't understand it to be honest, the directory I use for testing mwe from this site for example has at the moment 1508 aux files and 1689 tex files but I don't see why that interferes at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and others. Why is aux-directory/output-directory usefull? Well: I do have a SharePoint Document Management Site.
This is synchronised locally with OneDrive for Business in both directions. I can add locally files in a directory, it will be uploaded an there are a bunch of fields that will be filled automatically. And will be automatically versionized. For reasons I don't want to discuss this is how ot goes, including working directly in this directories! So you see, I DO NOT want all These files to be needed removed because otherwise you see these files in all lists. These file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But in real life, as described by Mia Mijarena Pienitz, you need to direct the aux files to a local folder, while the PDF goes to the server.